# If a finite $p-$ group has only one composition series show that it is cyclic

Tags: group-theory

If a finite $p-$ group has only one composition series show that it is cyclic.

What I tried:

Let $G$ be a finite p-group .Then $|G|=p^n$ for some $n$ .Now every group of order $p^{n-1}$ is normal in a group of order $p^n$ .

So I can form the composition series :

$\{e\}=H_0<H_1<H_2<.......<H_n=G$ where $H_i$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $p^i$ and $|\dfrac{H_{i+1}}{H_i}|=p$ which is simple.

How to proceed next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$G$ is a finite $p$-group and in a finite $p-$  group every maximal subgroup is a maximal  normal subgroup and so it has only one maximal subgroup $M$ .

In particular, since every proper subgroup of $G$ is contained in some maximal subgroup, every proper subgroup is contained in $M$.

Now, let $g \in G \setminus M$. Then $\langle g \rangle \le G$ is a subgroup of $G$ which is not contained in $M$, hence it is the whole $G$. So $G= \langle g \rangle$ is cyclic.

Comment: Let $N$ be another maximal subgroup. Then consider composition series of $M$ and $N$, $1 < \dots < M$ and $1 < \dots N$. Then these two can be extended to two different composition series of $G$: $1 < \dots < M < G$ and $1 < \dots < N < G$.

Comment: Simply add "$<G$" to the two previous composition series. The first two composition series are not of $G$. They are of $M$ and $N$.

Comment: $G$ is a nilpotent group, so every maximal subgroup is normal.

Comment: So: what is your knowledge about finite $p$-groups? Do you know that a simple $p$-group must be cyclic of order $p$?

Comment: I have edited the answer